# Why was my question marked as "subjective"?

Tags: support, asking-questions

This is in regards to [a question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8023/how-do-you-calculate-the-effects-of-precession-on-elliptical-orbits) I posted recently:

> Note: As I typed up the title to this question, the reminder box popped up on the right and said something along the lines of "This question is subjective and likely to be closed." Two thoughts of mine that could end up in meta: First off, is this question too subjective? Second, why did this appear? What keywords could possibly have set it off?

Why did the box pop up?

Answer (score 4):

With a little experimenting, it appears to be triggered by the <strike>words "do you"</strike> word "you" in the title. I can understand how they might think that the result would be subjective, but it doesn't seem like a solid teller. You can find the triggering words and the regex responsible for filtering for them in this [Meta SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-algorithm-does-stackoverflow-use-to-determine-if-a-question-may-be-subjecti).

As for your question, I don't think it would be considered subjective outside of the filter. You could replace "do you" with "does one" and get the same meaning and avoiding the filter, though this is really just semantics.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, read [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). If after reading it you still think asking subjective questions on this site is a good idea, I suggest you start a [discussion](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) and try to bring your administrators, community managers, and users on board. That specific part of the question validation can be turned off on a per-community basis, should you succeed.

Comment: Are you saying my question was too subjective?

Comment: Not as it stands currently. But it had to contain something that tripped up the algorithm that checks for subjective stuff

Comment: I'm guessing that was the "Do you" part, like Mitch said. By the way, the link was very helpful.